# Can we use Facebook workplace account for Facebook Login(Android SDK)?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-workplace

I wanted to know if Facebook Workplace credentials can be used to Login in an android app which uses Facebook Login?

If not, Is there any similar service provided by Facebook Workplace which we can use in Android app?

I went through Facebook Login Developer Docs as well as Facebook Workplace Developer Docs but could not find any clear mentioning about this.

Note: I tried using a Facebook Workplace account for Facebook Login method in our Android app but could not go through. This might be the answer but i want to be completely assured for it.

Answer (score 3):

check this out [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/developer-access] It states that workplace integration is for Enterprise purpose only

Comment: Link takes you to page not found as the last bracket is apart of the link - add a space between the brackets and the link (I cannot make the edit since it is so small)

Comment: Thanks @nitish29 i have had a look at it but needed Facebook Login like solution since we have it already in place. This integration is all new work.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **NO**. You need an fb developer account active which is only possible if you have a normal facebook login and not facebook workplace login.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Any reference or documentation link confirming this?

Comment: @binaryKarmic : Unfortunately there no documents for the confirmation. I gave the solution based on my experience. Even i was looking to use my workplace account for development but it didn't support  and it always works with my personal fb account. I guess we need more clarity from facebook on this.